# How do I get better at finding a CFG and PDA for a language?

Tags: grammar, theory, computation

I seem to be having a lot of trouble finding CFGs and PDAs for languages. Even with languages that are considered generally simple, I find myself taking too long to find a CFG and PDA for it. Am I simple overthinking it or does this skill just get better with practice?

Comment: Can you provide some more context on what you are currently doing?

Comment: I am taking a theory of computation course at my university and basically for our one of our assignment, we are given a language and asked to find a CFG and PDA for it. I am having a lot of trouble however.

Comment: People here do not necessarily know the exact acronyms you are using. What are CFG and PDA ?

Comment: Context free grammar and push down automata, but nvm I figured it out